# running a javascript cucumber capybara it halts

Tags: javascript, cucumber, capybara

I have this scenario:

```
Scenario: If coming from savsale.com directly then the submenu items should open the right items.
  Given the 'sales' page
  When the user chooses 'women/accessories' from the navigation menu
```

And this step:

```
When /^the user chooses '(.*?)\/(.*?)' from the navigation menu$/ do |menu,submenu|
  begin
    evaluate_script(%Q{console.debug('trying to show the menu:');})
    command1 = "$('##{menu} ul').attr('style','display:block;visibility:visible');"
    evaluate_script(%Q{console.debug("#{command1}");})
    evaluate_script(command1)
    evaluate_script(%Q{console.debug('first command done.');})
    command2 = "$('##{menu}').addClass('sfHover');"
```

I am also using the selenium webdriver:

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
```

The execution of javascript doesn't reaches this code:

```
evaluate_script(%Q{console.debug('first command done.');})
```

In the firefox console this is shown:

```
$('#women ul').attr('style','display:block;visibility:visible');
```

But this isn't:

```
first command done.
```

I think it halts at execute_script(command1), then it fails with timeout exception...:

```
When the user chooses 'women/accessories' from the navigation menu # features/step_definitions/steps.rb:193

  Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
```

Does anybody have a good idea?

Comment: After I realized that there is a execute_script on the object returned by the page I tried and it works... OMG... So it works fine.
...
    page.execute_script(command2)
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, after a while, I realized that there is a execute_script on the object returned by the page I tried and it works... OMG... So all the javascript are executed now...

```
When /^the user chooses '(.*?)\/(.*?)' from the navigation menu$/ do |menu,submenu|
  begin
    sleep 10.seconds #wait for the js to load the menus
    page.execute_script(%Q{console.debug('trying to show the menu:');})
    command2 = "$('##{menu}').addClass('sfHover');"
    page.execute_script(command2)
    command1 = "$('##{menu} ul').attr('style','display:block;visibility:visible');"
    page.execute_script(command1)
    command3 = "$('a[filter-category=#{menu}][filter-sub-category1=#{submenu}]')[0].click();"
    page.execute_script(command3)
    rescue Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError
  end
end
```